# how to use Jquery getScript caching using dynamically generated url

Tags: javascript, jquery, octobercms

I am looking for a way cache script with dynamically generated url I am currently using Octobercms that combines all scripts into one file on render I have seen in the past people using php but October cms uses blade the script I have looked at is this one

```
$.cachedScript( "ajax/test.js" ).done(function( script, textStatus ) {
  console.log( textStatus );
});
```

the problem I have is that the url the combined script is different on ever installation.

Comment: I am not sure about jquery but have you tried something like " $.cachedScript("{{ ['ajax/test.js']|theme }}").done(function(script, textStatus){
      console.log(textStatus);
  });"

Comment: I have got this to work  $.getScript('http://yoursite.com/test/combine/b075f6a5b111b3375ecc553c0d813ee5-1534276479', function() {
                  // Call custom function defined in script but get one error still "Velocity is already loaded"
                         });  still get one error "Velocity is already loaded" and as yet haven't found a method for dynamically generated url's

Comment: to get dynamic script url try this var path= $("script[src]:eq(1)").attr('src'); as jquery is zero base eq(1) is accually the second script file simply remove your url and quotes and replace with path

Comment: unfortunately user2033464 this doesn't work I can only get this to work if I hard code the url in my problem is the name of the js file is combined in octobercms and changes every time you refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to stop the problem with the "Velocity is already loaded" error by using the following

```
$("#loader").load(href, function(){
        delete jQuery.Velocity;
         $.getScript( "http://yoursite.com/test/combine/b075f6a5b111b3375ecc553c0d813ee5-1534701438", function() { 
     // Call custom function defined 
     });
```

just need to figure out how to replace "http://yoursite.com/test/combine/b075f6a5b111b3375ecc553c0d813ee5-1534701438" as this alters any help with this part of the code would be great I have tried user2033464 code but when I console.log(path); after $.getScript I get "ReferenceError: path is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem as follows

```
var path= $("script[src]:eq(1)").attr('src'); //needs to be globle to work in getScript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loader").load(href, function(){
        delete jQuery.Velocity;  // stops Velocity reloading error
         $.getScript( path, function() { // loads script into newly loaded page into existing page 
     // Call custom function defined 
     });
});
```

I hope the helps someone with similar problem thank user2033464 for your assistance